# Only a buyer can rate the product in Livewire:Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm using the Livewire rating system in my Laravel e-commerce application. Right now any user can rate and comment on any product. I want only the buyers can rate and comment.

ProductRatings.php

```
class ProductRatings extends Component
{
    public $rating;
    public $comment;
    public $currentId;
    public $product;
    public $hideForm;

    protected $rules = [
        'rating' => ['required', 'in:1,2,3,4,5'],
        'comment' => 'required',

    ];

    public function render()
    {
        $comments = Rating::where('product_id', $this->product->id)->where('status', 1)->with('user')->get();
        if(auth()->user()) {
            $user = Eorder::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
        }
        
        return view('livewire.product-ratings', compact('comments', 'user'));
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        if (auth()->user()) {
            $rating = Rating::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->where('product_id', $this->product->id)->first();
            if (!empty($rating)) {
                $this->rating  = $rating->rating;
                $this->comment = $rating->comment;
                $this->currentId = $rating->id;
            }
        }
        return view('livewire.product-ratings');
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $rating = Rating::where('id', $id)->first();
        if ($rating && ($rating->user_id == auth()->user()->id)) {
            $rating->delete();
        }
        if ($this->currentId) {
            $this->currentId = '';
            $this->rating  = '';
            $this->comment = '';
        }
    }

    public function rate()
    {
        $rating = Rating::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->where('product_id', $this->product->id)->first();
        $this->validate();
        if (!empty($rating)) {
            $rating->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            $rating->product_id = $this->product->id;
            $rating->rating = $this->rating;
            $rating->comment = $this->comment;
            $rating->status = 1;
            try {
                $rating->update();
            } catch (\Throwable $th) {
                throw $th;
            }
            session()->flash('message', 'Success!');
        } else {
            $rating = new Rating;
            $rating->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            $rating->product_id = $this->product->id;
            $rating->rating = $this->rating;
            $rating->comment = $this->comment;
            $rating->status = 1;
            try {
                $rating->save();
            } catch (\Throwable $th) {
                throw $th;
            }
            $this->hideForm = true;
        }
    }
}
```

product-ratings.blade.php

```
@auth
                            @if($hideForm != true)
                                <form wire:submit.prevent="rate()" class="form-horizontal" id="form-review">
                                    <div id="review"></div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group required">
                                        <div class="flex space-x-1 rating">
                                            <label class="control-label">Rating: </label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            <label for="star1">
                                                <input hidden wire:model="rating" type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" />
                                                <svg class="cursor-pointer block w-8 h-8 @if($rating>= 1 ) text-orange-400 @else text-grey @endif " fill=" currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                    <path d="M10 15l-5.878 3.09 1.123-6.545L.489 6.91l6.572-.955L10 0l2.939 5.955 6.572.955-4.756 4.635 1.123 6.545z" />
                                                </svg>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="my-5 ">
                                            @error('comment')
                                            <p class="mt-1 text-red-500">{{ $message }}</p>
                                            @enderror
                                            <label class="control-label" for="input-review">Your Review</label>
                                            <textarea wire:model.lazy="comment" name="description" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Comment.."></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="block">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Rate</button>
                                        @auth
                                        @if($currentId)
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" wire:click.prevent="delete({{ $currentId }})" class="text-sm cursor-pointer">Delete</button>
                                        @endif
                                        @endauth
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <div class="review-button">
                                <div class="mb-8 text-center text-gray-600">
                                    You need to login in order to be able to rate the product!
                                </div>
                                <a href="/register" class="px-5 py-2 mx-auto font-medium text-center text-gray-600 bg-white border rounded-lg shadow-sm focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-100" style="width:45%;padding:10px;display:block;float:left;margin-left:20px;">Register</a>
                                <a href="/login" class="px-5 py-2 mx-auto font-medium text-center text-gray-600 bg-white border rounded-lg shadow-sm focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-100" style="width:45%;padding:10px;display:block;float:left;margin-left:20px;">Login</a>
                            </div>
                        @endauth
```

Only auth users can comment and rate. I want only the users who ordered the product can comment.

Comment: Before I read all that: have you tried anything so far? I assume purchases end up in a DB, so when user X visits product Y's page, shouldn't you be able to figure out if they bought product Y? Also, your question sounds like you might not even be aware of this approach?

Comment: Yes I'm doing this for first time so I don't have any idea how can I write the code and where should I do it.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use `Livewire` yet. but I can show you how can it achieve in `laravel 8`. Check user purchase history. Use a variable to check user purchased the product or not.

```
$is_purchased = 0;
```

check user purchased the product or not. If purchased than change the value of `$is_purchased`

```
$purchased = Orders::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->where('product_id', $this->product->id)->first();
if($purchased){
    $is_purchased = 1;
}
```

send `$is_purchased` to your view and check it's value there

```
if($is_purchased == 1){
 // do rating stuff
}
```

by this you can allow rating only for those who purchased the product.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your mount() function like the below.

```
public function mount()
  {
    if (auth()->user()) {
      $rating = Rating::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)>where('product_id', $this->product->id)->first();


      $purchased = Orders::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->where('product_id', $this->product->id)->first();
      if ($purchased) {
        $this->hideForm = true;
      } else {
        $this->hideForm = false;
      }
      if (!empty($rating)) {
        $this->rating  = $rating->rating;
        $this->comment = $rating->comment;
        $this->currentId = $rating->id;
      }
    }
    return view('livewire.product-ratings');
  }
```